# Which spaces can be seen as to be the one-point compactification of some other space

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $X$, under what conditions is $X$ the one-point compactification of some other space $Y$? Obviously $X$ must be compact but it seems unlikely to me that every compact space arises from one-point compactification.

Comment: Certainly finite sets under the discrete topology are (counter)examples. Would it not suffice for $X$ to contain a limit point $x$, so that $Y=X-\{x\}$ works?

Comment: I'd disagree: I would say a discrete space with $n+1$ points is the one-point compactification of a discrete space with $n$ points @GregMartin

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: It is the Alexandroff extension, but not the one-point compactification, because it is not a compactification, because the discrete space with $n$ points is not dense in the discrete space with $n+1$ points. The Alexandroff extension is a compactification exactly if the original space is not compact.

Comment: @GregMartin: You also need that $\{x\}$ is closed.

Comment: @GregMartin: And even that is not sufficient. Counterexample: Be $Y=\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, and $X=\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ with the topology where a set is open if it is either an open subset of $\mathbb R$ or the full space. This clearly is a compact space, $\infty$ is a limit point (so it is indeed a compactification), and $\{\infty\}$ is closed (the condition I added above). Yet $X$ is not the one-point compactification of $Y=\mathbb R$ because e.g. $\{0\}$ is not closed in $X$, while in the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R$ it is.

Comment: Cool, thanks for articulating your expertise! So let's see, we'd need something like: the intersection of all neighborhoods of $x$ is $\{x\}$...?

Comment: @GregMartin: No, because it might be that this is not the case in $Y$ (there was no restriction to T1 spaces), and then it is also not the case in the one-point compactification of $Y$. What is needed is that all closed compact sets of $Y$ need still be closed in $X$. However at the moment I don't see an easy criterion that is simpler than “$X$ is the one-point compactification of $Y$ up to homeomorphism,”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any compact Hausdorff space $X$ with a non-isolated point $p\in X$ (so $\{p\}$ is not open) is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $Y:=X\setminus \{p\}$ by standard theorems.

A finite discrete space shows why we need the condition for a non-isolated point.